# How to insert Reference by using Wix Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velo

Let me start off by saying that Im thoroughly confused. 
So I've 2 collections - CCDB & IDB 
CCDB has the primary key of Champion ID(field key:champId, type:text) 
IDB has a primary key DeviceName(field:title, type:text) and a reference field Champion ID(field key: champId, type: reference). 
So, n items in the IDB collection belong to 1 item in CCDB collection.

Now, when I'm inserting data into IDB collection using following code below, the database shows a red underline saying :  "Cell value type is Number. Change to Reference."

**below is wix code

```
getitems("pc").then(res => {
let toInsert = {
 "title":  res[i].champion_id, //reference to CCDB
 "description": res[i].Description, 
 "deviceName": res[i].DeviceName,
 "itemId": res[i].ItemId 
} 
wixData.insert("IDB", toInsert)
  .then(results => {
    let item = results;
    console.log(item);
 })
.catch(err => {
 let errorMsg = err;
 console.log(errorMsg);
  });
})
```

[In IDB collection after insert operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDLuQ.jpg)

[CCDB holding the correct champId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDvAs.jpg)

```
"title":  (res[i].champion_id).toString(),
```

I tried to use toString in here too, but the collection then shows error : "reference is broken".

I searched the documentation and found  wixData.insertReference().. but im not sure how to use the method in this scenario or even if it is possible to use. 
And since the number of Items in IDB would be more than 100, I cant insert reference manually. How can I solve this with code? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something doesn't seem to add up between your description, code, and the screenshots.

You have the right idea, in that you should be using the ID from the CCBD collection in the reference field of the IDB collection, but it doesn't seem you've done it properly.

From your description, it would seem you need something like this:

```
let toInsert = {
 "title":  res[i].DeviceName,
 "description": res[i].Description, 
 "champId": res[i].champId, // this is the reference field, not title
 "itemId": res[i].ItemId 
}
```

But like I said, your description doesn't match what your code and screenshots seem to show, so it's hard to tell exactly what's going on.